# VB How to Limit Line number of RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have some problems with RichTextBox.I have to limit RTB's sizes regarding to required character number(10 for height 10 for width).I tried to limit the number of lines with using maxLength property.I mean i can limit the line length E.g. 10 if i define the max length as 100 there can be only 10 lines.Everything is ok without enter key. But when i press enter it does not count the rest of current line.If i press enter after 6th char of a line it skips to next line. And count previous line as 6.So box gets longer through downwards. Thanks in advance...My code is below.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyDown
    'Here im trying to count character number of each line

    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For Each s As String In Me.RichTextBox1.Lines
        count = count + 1
        MsgBox(count)

        Dim nextLineText As String = s

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If count < (TakeFromCombo(ComboBox1)) Then
                RichTextBox1.MaxLength = RichTextBox1.MaxLength - (TakeFromCombo(ComboBox1) - nextLineText.Length)
            End If
        End If

        'I tried to disable enter key at last line
        If count = TakeFromCombo(ComboBox1) Then
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: How about testing the RTB's `Lines.GetUpperBound(0)` in the `TextChanged` event?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can reach the number of lines.It is not the problem. The problem is i can't set the max line number cause of enter key.

Comment: Clearly the MaxLength property is entirely useless.  So don't use it.  You'd have to monitor with the KeyPress event.  Or just assume that the user is not an idjut and verify data entry with the Validating event.  Which also helps you deal with corner-cases like the user pasting text from the Clipboard.

Comment: Yeah it is completely useless. But im an intern in a Bank so i have to write it like even idiots can use.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? (Where rtb1 is your RichTextBox):

```
Private Sub rtb1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles rtb1.KeyDown
    If rtb1.Text.Length > 0 Then
        If rtb1.Lines.Count = 11 Then
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End If
        If rtb1.Lines(rtb1.GetLineFromCharIndex(rtb1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine)).Length > 9 And e.KeyCode <> Keys.Return Then
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The tools for manipulating this situation are a little crude. `GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine` returns the character index within the entire string of RTB text. `GetLineFromCharIndex(i)` gets the index of the line of text that contains i. `Lines()` returns an array of all the lines (which is just the text of the RTB, split on carriage returns, and `Lines(i)`, like any array, returns the member of the array at that index (found using the two previously described RTB methods).

Comment: Thank you for reply. But i can't understand the third if. I added the code.

Comment: The condition is: If currentLineLength > 9 and the user didn't just hit return. Does it work in your code?

Comment: I just added some detailed explanation of that line.

Comment: Also, the Lines.Count should = 11, not 10 as I first wrote.

Comment: Actually im in trouble with enter button :)  And it must be disabled only in the last row to avoid from exceeding the line number.Cause i have to preserve all other properties of RTB.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you're saying.

Comment: Thank you for replies.I think i can not explain . Last quesiton: the count in for each loop is not increasing. Is it possible to create a counter in for each loop?

Comment: `For lineCounter As Int32 = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1` followed later by `Next` (But I think you're making this a harder problem than it needs to be.)